How can I create parameterized matrices and generate the final matrix on demand with the parameters in Python?
I am in a situation where I need to work with parameterized matrices. For e.g., say I start with two matrices A and B,
A = [1 2]     B = [a b]
    [3 4]         [5 6]

Here matrix B is parameterized with the variables a and b. I might at some point need to combine the matrices, say using matrix multiplication, to get AB = C:
C = AB = [a+10   b+12 ]
         [3a+20  3b+24]


I would now like to store matrix C with those variables in there and have the ability to provide values for the variables and evaluate the elements. I.e. matrix C would be a matrix parameterized by the variables a and b.
Instead of generating C on the fly any time I need it by providing the parameters to B and doing all the matrix multiplications, I would like to store the general structure of the matrix C by doing the matrix multiplications once, with C inheriting any of the variables of its constituents. I am hoping this will save run time since the structure of matrix C is cached, i.e. I don't need to do the matrix operations every time I change a parameter.
In my case, there maybe many such matrices, each with their own variable elements and I might need to combine them arbitrarily (matrix products, Kronecker products etc.). I was wondering if there is an established way to achieve this in Python. It would also be helpful if the solution was performant as the there will be many matrix operations in the code I am trying to run. Unfortunately, I have to stick with Python for now, so solutions in other languages would be less helpful.
I have tried achieving this result using the sympy module, and I think I have a very crude setup going that seems to work, but I wanted to know if there was a more canonical way of doing this in Python. Also, I am not sure if sympy would be the most performant, and I am not sure if such a system can be obtained using numpy. A simplified version of my sympy code is given below for reference:
import sympy as s
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy.physics.quantum import TensorProduct as tp


A = Matrix([[1,2],
            [3,4]])

a, b = s.symbols('a b')
B = Matrix([[a,b],
            [5,6]])


# To obtain C, parameterized by a and b
C = A*B
display(C)

# Finally, to evaluate C with parameters a=3 and b=0.5
C_eval = C.evalf(subs={a:3, b:0.5})
display(C_eval)

# Or, to generate and evaluate a different combination of A and B
D = tp(A,B)
display(D)
D_eval = D.evalf(subs={a:3, b:0.5})
display(D_eval)


No, I made two edits. The first one added the sympy code. The next one added one more example in the sympy code.

The code you have looks fine. I'm not sure what question you are really asking here.

Sympy would seem the most recognised way to do symbolic manipulation with Python. (Otherwise you are onto completely different tools like Mathematica.) But, at the end of the day, you need one function to set your matrices and then a main function to do a prescribed set of calculations. So, show what you are actually trying to do and make a convincing case for leaving intermediate results with symbols in.

In terms of performance, doing more of the calculations numerically (numpy) may be better.  Things like matrix multiplication are done in highly optimized compiled code.  But that's better when the arrays are large, as opposed to a whole lot of (2,2) ones.  Try and test may be the only way of determining what's performant.

@jared , this is my first time posting to stackoverflow, so I am not overly familiar with the interface yet. When I submitted my question and it was in the "Staging Ground" I got your feedback comment and based on that edited my original question. I did not at any point delete the original post. I am not sure why those edits do not appear in the edit history. Perhaps because those were done before the post went public?

@smi Ah, that's it. I forgot this was in the staging ground. My apologies. I'll delete my comments soon so they don't distract people.

I could see here several solutions.
1. SimPy (your current solution)
SymPy great for this! It allows you cache expressions like matrix multiplications, but it's really primarily a symbolic library, so not well optimised for performance as other numeric libraries.
2. NumPy + numexpr
NumPy is extremely fast and you could combine it with numexpr:
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
B_expr = 'a * B1 + b * B2'
B1 =np.array([[1, 0],[0, 5]])
B2 = np.array([[0, 1],[0, 6]])

AB_expr = 'A1 * (a * B1 + b * B2)'
A1 = A

a_val = 3
b_val = 0.5
ne.evaluate(AB_expr, local_dict={'a':a_val,'b':b_val, 'A1':A1, 'B1': B1, 'B2': B2})

3. SymEngine
SymEngine is C++ based symbolic library and its much faster than SymPy. You could use it similar as SymPy by python library
import symengine as se
a, b = se.symbols('a b')
A = se.Matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
B =se.Matrix([[a, b],[5, 6]])
C = A * B
C_eval = C.subs({a: 3, b: 0.5})

So if you need couples symbolic logic and caching you could use SymPy or SymEngine
If you want more performance, you could use NumPy + numexpr
Also, for very complex operations you could read about Theano

Note that Theano has been deprecated – quote from the README: MILA has stopped developing Theano … The PyMC developers have forked Theano to a new project called PyTensor that is being actively developed: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pytensor

This looks very much like a ChatGPT answer to me.

But its not. Stackoverflow marking and deleting answers that were written by chatgpt
